# Ruby returns instance when iterates over custom class instances

Tags: ruby

Please help me understand the difference between iteration over the instances of String and over the instances of custom class.

```
a = ["pew", "pie"]
a.inject do |memo, instance|
  memo + instance
end
```

It works OK. Returns "pewpie" as expected.

```
class Boom
  def slash
    3
  end  

  def ping
    5
  end  
end

a = [Boom.new]
a.inject do |memo, instance|
  memo + instance.slash + instance.ping
end
```

This for some reason returns the instance itself - Boom:0x00000005018a38

Comment: There is only 1 element `Boom.new` in array. Hence it doesn't iterate through ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key point is this note in the `inject` documentation:
*If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.*

In your case you should do something like

```
a.inject(0) { |memo, instance| memo + instance.slash + instance.ping }
# 8
```

Otherwise you use a reference to an object of type Boom as memo.

Answer (score 2):

When there's no initial value for accumulator, the first element is used. And if there's only one element in array - the block will not run:

```
[1].inject{ raise "Boom!" }
 # => 1
[1].inject(0){ raise "Boom!" }
 # => RuntimeError: Boom!
```

So you need either provide initial value, of redefine the `+` operator for your class.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions:

```
a = [Boom.new, Boom.new, Boom.new]
# => [#<Boom:0x007ffaf90a9c08>, #<Boom:0x007ffaf90a9be0>, #<Boom:0x007ffaf90a9bb8>]

# 1) memo is a String
a.inject('') {|memo, instance| memo + instance.slash.to_s + instance.ping.to_s}
# => "353535"

# 2) memo is an Array
a.inject([]) {|memo, instance| memo << instance.slash.to_s + instance.ping.to_s}
# => ["35", "35", "35"]
```

*see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject*

Comment: Thanks! My bad. I should have read documentation with greater attention.